# How to automatically set the Signing Team on IOS cordova project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic3, fastlane

I am trying to automate the build/deployment of my hybdrid mobile application in Jenkins using fastlane.
I use ionic (v3.3.0) and cordova (v7.0.1) for the source. I use fastlane v2.36.0 and Xcode is version 8.3.2.

The command I run in the jenkins job

```
yarn
ionic cordova prepare
fastlane ios build
```

The fastlane/FastFile

```
platform :ios do
  before_all do
  end

  ios_project_path = "platforms/ios/awesomeproject.xcodeproj"

  desc "Build for IOS"
  lane :build do
    increment_build_number(
      xcodeproj: ios_project_path,
      build_number: ENV["BUILD_NUMBER"]
    )

    # Recreate schemes to ensure a smooth transition from cordova to gym
    recreate_schemes(project: ios_project_path)

    update_project_team(
      path: ios_project_path,
      teamid: "TEAMID"
    )

    #update_provisioning_profile_specifier(xcodeproj: ios_project_path)


      gym(scheme: "awesomeproject",
          configuration: "Debug",
          clean: true,
          project: ios_project_path,
          output_directory: "target")
  end
end
```

The fastlane/Appfile

```
package_name "com.xxx.awesomeapp"

app_identifier "com.xxx.awesomeapp" # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id "xxx.xxxx@xxx.com" # Your Apple email address

team_id "TEAMID" # Developer Portal Team ID
```

The command `fastlane ios build` is failing on the gym instruction with the error

> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS
>   10.3'

The detailed error in the fastlane log is

> Check dependencies Signing for "awesomeproject" requires a development
>   team. Select a development team in the project editor. Code signing is
>   required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS
>   10.3'

The xcode project generated by Cordova has the Automatic signing activated but it is missing the Signing Team.
The workaround I used so far is to manually select the Team with Xcode the first time the platform/ios folder is generated. But if I remove the platform folder generated by cordova, I need to redo the selection of the team in XCode.

Is there a way to select with Cordova or any fastlane plugin the Signing team? I am open to use any solution, script.
So my build will be fully automated. The update_project_team instruction is not working.

Answer (score 14):

Create a file called `build.json` in the root directory of your project, with the Team ID and provisioning profile GUID you want to use to sign the app:

`build.json`:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "provisioningProfile": "{your development profile}",
      "developmentTeam": "{your Team ID}",
      "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "provisioningProfile": "{your distribution profile}",
      "developmentTeam": "{your Team ID}",
      "packageType": "app-store"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when you build using the Cordova CLI, these signing credentials will be used.

Note: according to the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#signing-an-app) the above syntax is deprecated for Xcode 8 and iOS 10, and the provisioning profile GUID is no longer needed. However, I've been unable to get it working without specifying the provisioning profile using Cordova v7.0.1.

Comment: Is it the same with cordova-8 ?

Comment: @rahulinaction, it works fine with cordova 10.0.0